# Can't use ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `ngFor` loop to get data from my array. I get this

> "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'.NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays".

How can I fix it?

how i get data

```
if (this.resources$) {
  this.resources$.subscribe(result => {
    if (result)  {
      this.resourcesList = <Resources[]>result;

      this.showResources = true;
    }
  });



export interface Resources {
 Id: number;
 Name: string; 
}
```

I am trying to use it like that

```
<div *ngFor="let res of resourcesList">{{res.Name}}</div>
```

Comment: syntax looks correct. Please check the content of  the resourceslist variable. set a breakpoint or display: {{ resourcesList | json }}

Comment: Maybe your  resourcesList doesn't get set, because you never get into the wrapping if condition? Could you please try to log this? And by the way - You should be able to DOM subscribe with async pipe directly to your resources$ Observable: *ngFor="let res of resources$ | async". Using this you dont need anything of your .ts logic, just the resources$ observable.

Comment: Check what your backend is returning, make sure it's an array, not an object containing an array.

Comment: result = {Resources: Array(1), ItemCount = 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment on another answer, your backend returns an object in this format:

```
{
  "ItemsCount": 1,
  "Resources": [
    {
      "Name": "Garaż wolnostojący 1",
      "DerivedFullName": "Garaż wolnostojący 1",
      "ParentId": 0,
      "IsLinkPossible": true,
      "Children": [],
      "Code": "",
      "Path": "Garaż wolnostojący 1",
      "Description": "",
      "Id": 186973
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is not an array, the array is in `response.Resources`, so doing this:

```
this.resourcesList = <ResourcesDetailsToIssueResponse[]>result.Resources;
```

will probably do the job for you.

Comment: Yes Thank you  it is work

Answer (score 2):

you can use `keyvalue` pipe if you want to iterate over a object.

```
<div *ngFor="let res of resourcesList | keyvalue">
    {{res | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: <ResourcesDetailsToIssueResponse[]> I thinks it's a list

Comment: It is work and display all values. When i am trying to gest res.Name do not.

Comment: can you show me your response. `{{res | json}}` what it will show?

Comment: `keyvalue` pipe is convert your response in to `key` `value` pair

Comment: you can get name by using this 
`{{res.value?.name}}`

Comment: @BartoszStępak is it working ?

Comment: @ala NVM but it is obj you can see in error :)

Comment: @YashRami I added an answer, check it. He's doing what I actually thought he was doing in my comment to the question few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

1. `resourcesList` must be an array.
2. Initialize `resourcesList` to an empty array i.e `public resourcesList : any = []`
3. make sure the response send by `this.resources$.subscribe(...)` is array of object
4. change `<div *ngFor="let res of resourcesList">{{res?.Name}}</div>`